# How to reverse a column in SAS by an specific ID?

Tags: sorting, sas, dataset, proc-sql

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
+----+------------+-------+
| ID | ID_Count   | Count |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |        1.1 |     5 |
|  1 |        1.2 |     4 |
|  1 |        1.3 |     3 |
|  2 |        2.1 |     4 |
|  2 |        2.2 |     2 |
|  3 |          3 |     0 |
|  4 |        4.1 |     5 |
|  4 |        4.2 |     3 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

I want to reverse the group in the Count column where ID is the same as the previous one, but without reverse the ID column. My result should look like this:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| ID | ID_Count   | Count |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |        1.1 |     3 |
|  1 |        1.2 |     4 |
|  1 |        1.3 |     5 |
|  2 |        2.1 |     2 |
|  2 |        2.2 |     4 |
|  3 |          3 |     0 |
|  4 |        4.1 |     3 |
|  4 |        4.2 |     5 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

The ID_Count is just a column to show that the order of the ID's should not be changed.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Show what you have tried and what errors were encountered. One approach is to use two group-wise DOW loops, the first that loads a hash as a LIFO stack, and the second unloads the LIFO stack. Another is to presume a maximum group size and use a temporary array as the LIFO stack.

Comment: Why does ID_COUNT for ID=3 not follow the pattern of the other values?  Why not just remove ID_COUNT and recreate it?

Comment: The ID_Count is a variable that is used for other variables of the dataset, so it can't be excluded. It follows the rule that when the ID repeats, it gets the shape "<ID>-<count>", and when it doesn't, it gets "<ID>".

Comment: If you know the rule you can recreate it.  I am curious how that format works when there are more than 9 repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's probably a more straight forward way of doing this but the following should work:

Step 1: add a ROWNO to your first data set:

```
data have_row;
retain ROWNO;
set have;
if _n_ = 1 then ROWNO = 0;
ROWNO = ROWNO + 1;
run;
```

Step 2 create the order you are looking for and add ROWNO:

```
proc sort data = have out = have_order;
by ID, Count;
run;

data have_order;
retain ROWNO;
set have_order;
if _n_ = 1 then ROWNO = 0;
ROWNO = ROWNO + 1;
run;
```

step 3 combine the data:

```
proc sql noprint;
create want as
select a.id,b.id_count,a.count
from (select * from have_order)as a
left join
select * from have_row as b
on a.rowno=b.rowno;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea you gave of how to deal with the problem solved the problem. I simplificated some of the code you gave and it is really fine to use.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary array as stack is a simple approach.  Output will halt with an error at the point a group has more rows then the temporary array has slots.  In this example there are 10,000 slots.

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='|';
input id id_count count;
datalines;
|  1 |        1.1 |     5 |
|  1 |        1.2 |     4 |
|  1 |        1.3 |     3 |
|  2 |        2.1 |     4 |
|  2 |        2.2 |     2 |
|  3 |          3 |     0 |
|  4 |        4.1 |     5 |
|  4 |        4.2 |     3 |
run;

* serial dows;

data want;
  array stack[10000] _temporary_;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    stack[_n_] = count;
  end;
  do _n_ = _n_ to 1 by -1;
    set have;
    count = stack[_n_];
    output;
  end;
run;
```